# C - Unable to free a malloced struct

Tags: c, struct, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I am attempting to create a simple family tree program in C, however I am encountering an issue where an instance of the following struct refuses to be free and i am getting a memory leak

```
typedef struct Person {
    struct person* *parents[2];
    struct person* partner;
    struct person* *children[32];
} person;
```

the accompanying struct which encompasses it is this

```
typedef struct Tree {
    person* top;
    person* current;
} tree;
```

the Tree struct frees just fine, however when I attempt to free the malloced memory of the person struct, I get a memory leak I am pretty sure indicates that memory.

```
void newPerson(tree *t){
    person *p = malloc(sizeof(person));
...
```

this is the function where the memory is malloced

```
...
if (t->current){
t->top = p; 
t->current = p; 
...
```

within the same function, both pointers are set to point to p.

```
int main(){
    tree *t = malloc(sizeof(tree));
    t->current = NULL;
    newPerson(t);
    free(t->current);
    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the code within the main function where the tree variable is created, and where it is freed. From the various ways ive been trying to fix this, the following happened.

1. If I put free(p) within the same function the Person is created, everything works fine and there are no errors nor memory leaks
2. If I try to free t->current, I get a leak sanitiser error telling me of a direct leak exactly where the Person is allocated
3. If i try to free t->top, I get a SEGV on unknown address error.

Now I know the issue is somewhere with t, but I have the faintest of clue as to what the issue actually is, either my knowledge of malloc and free has degraded to the point where im doing something wrong and i can't see it, or something else is going on.

Edit: Reprex

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Branch {
    struct branch* otherbranch;
} branch;

typedef struct Tree {
    branch* root;
    branch* current;
} tree

void newBranch(tree *t){
    branch *b = malloc(sizeof(branch));
    b->otherbranch = NULL;
    if (t->current){
        t->root = b; 
        t->current = b; 
    }
    //free(b); //case 1 where freeing works
}

int main(){
    tree *t = malloc(sizeof(tree));
    t->current = NULL;
    newBranch(t);
    free(t->root); //case 3 where segv occurs
    //free(t->current); //case 2 where memory leak occurs
    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are hiding relevant code. Please provide a [mre], which demonstrates your observation.

Comment: In `newPerson`, what do you do with the `malloc`ed `p` when `t->current` is `NULL`?

Comment: @Yunnosch Everything between the if statement and the mallocing of p in the newPerson block is just variable assignments of p, which at the moment are null, as there only exists one person

Comment: @IanAbbott The if statement is within the newPerson block and checks if t->current is null, (which it is, from main) and assigns it to point to p

Comment: You can leave irrelevant code out of your MRE. But please provide one.

Comment: @Yunnosch Added the reprex

Comment: @BBite The code you posted assigns `p` to `t->current` when `t->current` is *not* null, not when `t->current` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you enter this code

```
void newBranch(tree *t){
    branch *b = malloc(sizeof(branch));
    b->otherbranch = NULL;
    if (t->current){
        t->root = p; 
        t->current = p; 
    }
    //free(b); //case 1 where freeing works
}
```

t->current is null, so you never set t->root or t->current.

you then return to main and do `free(t->root)`, t->root is invalid at this point. You probably want to initialize t->root to NULL and maybe t->current too

i also assume you mean `t->root = b` not `= p` since there is no p i can see

Comment: my fault when doing the reprex, ive edited the post to fix that

Comment: Ah I see, I completely forgotten to include within the if statement an ! to check if it is null not if it is not null. This was a stupid error thats my fault